# Extract the content in a swf file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, swfobject, decompiling

I have an .swf file and i need to extract the content inside the .swf file in this case are .mp3 files, is there any way to parse or decompile the .swf file to extract its content?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything about .NET in there. Give SwfDotNet a try. I've half implemented it in the past but the project was abandoned. There's a tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16834/How-to-create-a-simple-SWF-decompiler-with-the-Swf

Answer (score 0):

Sothink SWF Decompiler should do the trick.

[Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/)

There is a free trial version available.

Comment: How can I decompile my .swf file within the .net framework with Sothink SWF Decompiler?

Comment: Are you trying to say you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I need to do it programmatically.